# Gauss reduction with result even-vector

Tags: c, matrix, gaussian

I code in C language. I have an matrix ***A***, I reduce this matrix *modulo 2* and call the result ***B***.

Now, I would like to solve ***B * X = C*** where ***C*** is an even-vector (all values of this vector are even) indeed, I would like ***C*** was a 0-vector modulo 2.

If I try to use Gauss reduction with ***C*** equal to 0-vector, so naturally he give me all coefficients *x_i* of ***X*** equal to 0.

I don't know how make for have an Gauss reduction (with not all the *x_i* values equal to 0)  give a even-vector...

Maybe a little picture for more comprehension : [link for the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UC0j.jpg)

My code is :

```
int valAbs( int n ) {
    return ( n < 0 ) ? -n : n;
}

// Alloc a matrice nb_lignes (lines) * nb_colonnes (columns)
// Where nb_colonnes = nb_lignes + 1 because I put the vector C in the
// last column
int ** newMatrice( unsigned long long int nb_lignes, unsigned long long int nb_colonnes ) {

    int **mat = malloc( nb_lignes * sizeof( int* ) );

    for ( unsigned long long int i=0; i < nb_lignes; i++ ) {
        mat[ i ]= malloc( nb_colonnes * sizeof( int ) );
    }

    return mat;
}

// If you want print the system :
void afficheSysteme( int **m, unsigned long long int nb_lignes, unsigned long long int nb_colonnes ) {

    printf(" /\n");

    for ( unsigned  long long int i = 0; i < nb_lignes; i++ ) {

        printf("|  ");

        for( unsigned  long long int j = 0; j < nb_colonnes; j++ ) {

            if( j != nb_colonnes - 1 ) {

                if( m[ i ][ j ] >= 0 && j )
                    printf( " + " );

                printf( "%3d*X%llu", m[ i ][ j ], j );
            }
            else {
                printf( " = %3d  (L%llu)", m[ i ][ j ], i );
            }
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    printf( " \\ \n" );
}


// Apply Gauss
void gauuss( int **m, unsigned long long int nb_ligne, unsigned long long int nb_colonne,  double *sol ) {

    for( unsigned long long int col = 0; col < nb_colonne - 1; col++) {

        // Get pivot line
        unsigned long long int lignePiv = getPivot( m, col, nb_ligne );


        //permutat line 'col' (where we are) and lignePiv (line of pivot)
        for ( unsigned long long int i = 0; i < nb_colonne; i++ ) {
            int tmp = m[ col ][ i ];
            m[ col ][ i ] = m[ lignePiv ][ i ];
            m[ lignePiv ][ i ] = tmp;
        }

        // Simplify the other lines
        for( unsigned long long int i = col + 1; i < nb_ligne; i++ ) { //pour chaque nb_ligne
            //    (nb_ligne col) * m[ col + 1 ][ col ]
            //    (nb_ligne i) * -m[ col ][ col ]
            int coef_piv= m[ i ][ col ];
            int coef_ligni = m[ col ][ col ];

            // For all colums
            for( unsigned long long int j = col; j < nb_colonne; j++ ) { 
                m[ i ][ j ] = coef_piv * m[ col ][ j ] - coef_ligni * m[ i ][ j ];
            }
        }

    }


    // Solve système

    sol[ nb_ligne - 1 ] = 0;

    if( m[ nb_ligne - 1 ][ nb_colonne - 2 ] != 0 )
        sol[ nb_ligne - 1 ] = (double) ( m[ nb_ligne - 1 ][ nb_colonne - 1 ] ) / (double) ( m[ nb_ligne - 1 ][ nb_colonne - 2 ] );


    //fill in the solutions table (opposite direction)
    for( unsigned long long int i = nb_ligne - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) { 
        double sigma = 0;


        for ( unsigned long long int j = i + 1; j <= nb_ligne - 1; j++ ) { 

            //calcul of sigma
            sigma += m[ i ][ j ] * sol[ j ];
        }

        sol[ i ] = 0;

        if( m[ i ][ i ] != 0 )
            sol[ i ] = ( m[ i ][ nb_ligne ] - sigma ) / m[ i ][ i ];

        if( i == 0 )
            break;
    }
}

//Pseudo application
// For exemple, I try to solve :
// 0x + 0y = 0 mod 2;
// 1x + 1y = 0 mod 2;
unsigned long long int nb_lines = 2;
unsigned long long int nb_columns = 3;

int ** matrix = newMatrice( nb_lines, nb_columns );

// Initialize coefficients 
matrix[ 0 ][ 0 ] = 0;
matrix[ 0 ][ 1 ] = 0;
matrix[ 1 ][ 0 ] = 1;
matrix[ 1 ][ 1 ] = 1;

// Initialize vector C
matrix[ 0 ][ 2 ] = 0;
matrix[ 1 ][ 2 ] = 0;

// Try gauss
double *sol = calloc( nb_lines,  sizeof( double ) );

gauuss( matrix, nb_lines, nb_columns, sol );

// show solutions
printf( ">>> Solutions <<<\n" );
for( unsigned long long int i = 0; i < nb_lines; i++ ) {
    printf( "\tx%llu = %.3f\n", i, sol[i] );
}
```

The result of execution of this code give me :

```
x0 = 0.000
x1 = 0.000
```

What is interests me is to find a combination of different  columns of the matrix where the sum is the 0-vector modulo 2. For example if we take coefficients of this matrix,

```
0 + 0 = 0 // 0 is even
1 + 1 = 2 // 2 is even
```

So I would like x0 = 1 and x1 = 1

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Modify the Gaussian reduction algorithm to solve `Bx = c` modulo 2.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry if my post is not really clear, I don't know how present that more clearly...

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for your answer. But how I must to choose the vector C coefficients ?

Comment: Since you are doing arithmetic modulo 2, `C` is the 0-vector as you say in your question. All of its elements are zero.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks. But when I put C equal to 0-vector, the program give me all coefficients `x_i of X` equal to 0. And it's normal no ? Or I have a bad algorithm ?

Comment: There may be a bug in your implementation. I suggest that you use a debugger or `printf()` statements to step through your code and see what it is doing.

Comment: Maybe this question is a better fit for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Paul assuming that you are trying to solve the matrix over GF(2), that's correct: all 0-vector is the answer to your problem, and that is the only answer because the matrix is linearly independent.  If the rows had a dependency (they do not), then there would be other solutions.  So your implementation is working for this example.  If you post the entire code, we can check whether it works for all examples.

Comment: Tanks for all your response ! 
@TheGreatContini I try to edit my Quesiton and put the code

Comment: @TheGreatContini,  I just come to put the code on my question

Comment: @Paul Quote: `So I would like x0 = 1 and x1 = 1` That does not seem a valid solution. If `x1` is 1 then (according to your picture), **C** [0] must be 1 as well and that conflicts with **C** % 2 being all zeros

Comment: @Paul I deleted my answer as it has become unclear what you are asking

Comment: @4386427 , I changed my image for her to match the code. What is interests me is to find a combination of different columns of the matrix where the sum is the 0-vector modulo 2. And so if we take `x0 = 1 and x1 = 1` we have `0 * 1 + 0 * 1 = 0` ( 0 = 0 mod 2) and `1 * 1 + 1 * 1 = 2` (2 = 0 mod 2)

Comment: @paul Quote: "What is interests me is to find a combination of different columns of the matrix where the sum is the 0-vector modulo 2" That was exactly what my answer did